# Connect to Raspberry Pi remote using IP Address

Tags: networking, ssh, raspicam, remote, port-forwarding

I have a raspberry pi web cam set up at our vacation home.  As soon as I got back to our real home, I am no longer able to view the web cam (I now know that I only have it set up with the local IP Address...)  Is there a way to connect to the raspberry pi from my real home remotely?  I have all the information from raspberry pi's ifconfig:

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr bx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  
          inet addr:192.168.xx.xx  Bcast:192.168.xx.xx  Mask:255.xxx.xxx.xx
          inet6 addr: fxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:xxxx  Metric:1
```

With this information, will this be enough to get into my raspberry pi remotely?  If not, what additional information would I need so that when I go back to my vacation home I can get it set up correctly.

Comment: assuming you are running a router at the vacation home you can't get back in without forwarding the appropriate ports. You will also need a way to get the IP address of the router.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of... oh well. I'll get it as soon as I go back.  Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to port forward the necessary ports ON YOUR VACATION HOUSE ROUTER to be able to remotely access it. You would also need to know your public IP address. You can find it here (http://www.whatsmyip.org). Guides to help you port forward are down here

Wikihow
http://m.wikihow.com/Set-Up-Port-Forwarding-on-a-Router

Comment: Yep.  That's what I assumed.  I was hoping there was another way.  I'll get it as soon as I go back to the vacation house.  Thanks!